# How to do total ordering in Apache Spark without encountering OOM?

Tags: apache-spark, sql-order-by, row-number

I need to have an rank id for my dataframe, based on a score , a simple row_number() over (order by score) as rank_id gives me OOM since all data is collected to a single machine. e.g.

```
select *, row_number() over (order by score) as rank_id from tbl order by score
```

monotonically_increasing_id() doesn't produce things that I want neither since I need consecutive rank ids.
The same thing is fairly straightforward to do in MapReduce, but I didn't find a way to do it in Spark, which is curious...

Answer (score 0):

I have some time to consider this problem, although 1) I think a traditional Oracle DB could be better here, and 2) I note that Databricks is real slow at the moment.

Anyway, Spark works per partition (parallelism) and not over partitions for better throughput, that is the issue. I am not sure in MR it would be easier, but if so, then use that, although that is less in vogue now.

I did my own thing and this works with rank/dense rank using *Range Partitioning* which means that for ranges of values the same value falls in and only into 1 partition, so you can apply your ranking and then overall ranking through some smarts, i.e. offsets, relying on range partitioning having ascending values in ascending partitions. Not entirely sure caching was all good, but for a small amount of data took a while, but I think many people are indoors studying due to the you-know-what situation.

Also, this is a good source: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/range-partitioning-apache-spark-sql/read

**Code**

```
// Took some short cuts on names of fields, concentrated more on algorithm itself to avoid single partition aspect

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

case class X(id: Long, name: String, amount: Double)
```

The data:

```
// Gen example data via DF
val df = Seq(
         (10, "order 1", 2000d), (11, "order 2", 240d), (12, "order 3", 232d), (13, "order 4", 100d), (214, "order 5", 11d), (15, "order 6", 1d),
         (2141, "order 7", 390d), (17, "order 8", 30d), (18, "order 9", 99d), (19, "order 10", 55d),  (20, "order 11", 129d), (21, "order 11", 75d), (15, "order 13", 1d)
        ).toDF("id", "name", "amount")
```

Processing:

```
// Make a Dataset, makes it easier with Class in RDD conversion and back again to DF/DS
val ds = df.as[X]

// Num partitions for parallel processing so as to increase throughput, n can be anything, but you will get better throughput
// Range partitioning has all values of same value in same partition - that is the clue here
// dense and non-dense rank possibilities, not just order by row number as in your example
val n = 5
val rdd= ds.repartitionByRange(n, $"amount")
   .rdd 
   .mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, iter) => {
      iter.map(x => (index, x ))   
    })
val df2 = rdd.toDF().cache
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tab1")
//Get the ranking per range partition
val res1 = spark.sql("""select *, rank() over (partition by _1 order by _2.amount asc) as RANK from tab1 """).cache
//res1.rdd.getNumPartitions // the number of partitions do not change, partitioning rangePartitioning maintained

res1.createOrReplaceTempView("tab2") 
// Get max val per partition, needs caching ideally, write to disk to avoid oddities in recomputation and caching bugs or not or what not. Not always convinced it works.
spark.sql("drop table if exists MAXVALS")
spark.sql(""" create table MAXVALS as select 'dummy' as dummy, _1, max(RANK) as max_rank from tab2 GROUP BY _1 UNION SELECT 'dummy', -1, 0  """)
val resA = spark.table("MAXVALS")
// Get offsets
val resB = resA.withColumn("cum_Max_RANK", sum("max_rank").over(
  Window
    .partitionBy("dummy")
    .orderBy(col("_1")) ))
resB.createOrReplaceTempView("tabC")

//So all the stuff works in parallel, but does it really help??? Is an RDBMS not better then???
val finalResult = spark.sql("""  select tab2._2, (tab2.RANK + tabC.cum_Max_RANK) as OVERALLRANK from tab2, tabc  where tabc._1 = (tab2._1 -1) ORDER BY OVERALLRANK ASC  """)
finalResult.show(false)
```

**Results**

```
+----------------------+-----------+
|_2                    |OVERALLRANK|
+----------------------+-----------+
|[15, order 6, 1.0]    |1          |
|[15, order 13, 1.0]   |1          |
|[214, order 5, 11.0]  |3          |
|[17, order 8, 30.0]   |4          |
|[19, order 10, 55.0]  |5          |
|[21, order 11, 75.0]  |6          |
|[18, order 9, 99.0]   |7          |
|[13, order 4, 100.0]  |8          |
|[20, order 11, 129.0] |9          |
|[12, order 3, 232.0]  |10         |
|[11, order 2, 240.0]  |11         |
|[2141, order 7, 390.0]|12         |
|[10, order 1, 2000.0] |13         |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

**Conclusions**

It works. But is there any point to it all? Yes, as getting the job done is always better than OOM's.

- The initial computations can be done in parallel for ordering, but require a `repartitionByRange`.
- But the overall final statement requires a sort if you want to guarantee the sort order (for a collect, show).
- The .explain does not show a single partition situation, but it would have to be tested at scale. That said, the OOM can be avoided and I suspect that unnecessary sorting goes on. May be `sortWithinPartition` could be a goer, but I left that out for now.
- Added some logic to the initial code below so as to see if Optimizer could be persuaded to avoid a shuffle, but it looks as though unnecessary shuffling occurs still when the .explain() output assessed. Room for improvement.

**Modified clause to try and influence Catalyst**

```
 val finalResult = spark.sql("""  select tab2._1 as Z, tab2._2, (tab2.RANK + tabC.cum_Max_RANK) as OVERALLRANK from tab2, tabc  where tabc._1 = (tab2._1 -1) ORDER BY Z ASC, OVERALLRANK ASC  """)
```

**Final Comment to questioner**

The person is looking for a one-liner code approach which is understandable. Functionality it is clear what is needed, but the OOM proves the point that it is technically not possible, else there was no OOM. The single partition approach needs to be bypassed, and this is such a method using more parallelism is required. The partition approach is the fundament of Spark.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that's exactly my point: it takes quite some code to do a seemingly basic thing, I wonder why there's no one-liner solution that works. For the range partition thing, my score varies and shifts over time, so it's not a write and forget solution.

Comment: There is NOT. This is Spark.

Comment: Actually it is a write and forget solution... what do you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that we need to know the values of the repartition field to do range partitioning, but it seems to work with any value, right?

Comment: indeed that is the case

Answer (score 0):

Actually my colleague gave me a solution that I found clean and concise, which is to use [zipwithindex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zipWithIndex()), in pyspark it would be something like:

```
df
 .select('score', 'user_id')
 .rdd
 .sortBy(lambda a: a[0], ascending= False)
 .zipWithIndex()
 .map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1])).take(3)
```

Comment: I looked at the DAG and just looking at the code. clean and concise, for smaller amounts of data sure thing. If larger data and more bandwidth not so sure. If it indeed solves the original query, then it says something about the current optimization in Spark. So please confirm in your answer it did so. My answer anyway, addresses the original issue technically, but we need to see the run-time of yours. The DAGs are not easy to interprete, interesting stuff.

Comment: 10M rows 10 min 2 cores. I guess it's doable. But all docs point to lesser performance.

Comment: my data has almost one billion rows, we use some cloud-based infrastructure so it's hard to say concrete things about performance, but it's definitely doable within hours

Comment: Yep that could well be the case, but anyway

Comment: As a final note, what it also means is when the going gets tough other approaches will need to apply and one will not be well-versed.